# Change input value with useRef

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I captured an element with the useRef hook of React.
if I use console.log(this.inputRef) I get:

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" class="MuiInputBase-input-409 MuiInput-input-394" placeholder="Type ItemCode or scan barcode" type="text" value="2">
```

Is there a way to change the value of that element using this.inputRef? and then force its re-render?

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but assuming `this.inputRef` is a reference to the element as the name implies, `this.inputRef.value = 'foo'` should work

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a ref rather than state? If you manage the inputs value in state (rather than keeping a ref to the element itself) the process generally becomes much cleaner. Relevant [React forms documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: because the onchange function is declared inside the input component not from the father. So I would like to trigger it from the father component usinf the ref

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the **ImperativeHandle** hook.

From React docs:

> useImperativeHandle customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using ref

The below code should work for you:

```js
function ValueInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    changeValue: (newValue) => {
      inputRef.current.value = newValue;
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" class="MuiInputBase-input-409 MuiInput-input-394" placeholder="Type ItemCode or scan barcode" type="text" value="2">
}
ValueInput = forwardRef(ValueInput);
```

Documentation (*updated*): https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle

Comment: And how do you call this from the parent component?

Comment: Hi @coler-j, take a look at the documentation link in my answer. It says "In this example, a parent component that renders <FancyInput ref={inputRef} /> would be able to call inputRef.current.focus()." So you can use your `ref` to call it :)

Answer (score 1):

well, you could do:

```
<input ref={myRef} value={myRef.current.value} />
```

The only problem with that is that refs DO NOT update or reredender the component, so,  the value would never update... rather than that it could throw you an error where you are attempting to make an uncontrolled input as controlled

Answer (score -4):

**may be this can help**

```
return(
    <input type="text" ref={inptRef}  />
    <button onClick={()=>inptRef.current.value = ""}>clear input</button>

)
```